# Background gradient

Tags: android

I have a typical login screen(table layout). What I would like to do is draw a rectangle around those controls and put gradient in it. How do I do that in xml ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create `gradient.xml` in `/res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

and in your layout file add `android:background="@drawable/gradient"` to the propierties of the container where the controls are put in

Answer (score 6):

Create a Layout with a Drawable Gradient background and inside that your real layout.

For example, create mygrandientbg_xml in drawables dir like:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns...">
 <gradient
     android:startColor="#255779"
     android:centerColor="#3e7492"
     android:endColor="#a6c0cd"
     android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Then create a FrameLayout like that

```
<FrameLayout
  ....
  android:background="@drawable/mygrandientbg"
  android:padding=20dip
 >
 put you layout here and set it to "centered"
```

You can find more info on Drawable Shapes here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape